# Multi variable range based for loop c++

Tags: c++, for-loop, range-based-loop

Can I write a range based for loop in c++ with two parallel iterators

I have code like this -

```
class Result{
    ...
    ...
};

std::vector<Result> results;
std::vector<Result> groundTruth(2);

int gtIndex = 0;
for(auto& r:results){
    auto gt = groundTruth[gtIndex];
    // compare r and gt

    gtIndex++;
}
```

I access elements from the `groundTruth` using `gtIndex`.

Question : How do I include the ground truth iterator in the `range based for loop` in C++.
In python I am aware of `zip` function which does this, but could not find anything like that in C++.

Comment: If your compiler supports C++23 there's https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/zip_view

Comment: @UnholySheep using c++ 20

Comment: ranges-v3 has also zip_view.

Comment: Then there's nothing like that in C++, for you.

Comment: Other alternative could be https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/iterator/doc/zip_iterator.html

Comment: Depending of your work [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)/[`std::transform_reduce`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform_reduce) might fit.

Comment: @Nitron_707 If you want something simple, you could create your own. [here's a start](https://godbolt.org/z/4nfToGTsn)

Comment: @TedLyngmo: not as easy to have it **correct**, you mutate `s` in your first loop, whereas we might expect to work on copy...

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, I made a quick and simple version especially to be able to mutate both `s` and `i` in the loop. Making it correct w.r.t. expectations was unfortunately lost. It was meant as inspiration - something to work on.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know any easy way to get what you want, however, you can get halfway there by using a reference to the elements of groundTruth instead array indexing.

First, you may want to verify sizes:

```cpp
using result_vector = std::vector<Result>;
void check_sizes( result_vector const& v1, result_vector const& v2 )
{
    if (v1.size() != v2.size())
        throw std::runtime_error("Size mismatch");
}
```

Then you can run your loop with just two or three extra lines of boilerplate (two if you do not need to check sizes):

```cpp
check_sizes(results, groundTruth);
auto it{ std::begin(groundTruth) };
for (auto& r : results) {
    auto& g{ *it++ };     // r and g are both references to Result

    // compare r and g
    if (r == g) {
        // ...
    }
}
```